# How to send multiple ranges in the body of an email through Excel?

Tags: html, excel, outlook, vba

I want to create a macro to generate an email to send out by sending two separate ranges from an xlsm file. I've used Ron De Bruin's code from here :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519602(v=office.11).aspx

Specifically the range to html function and the mail selection range outlook body macro. However, I am very new to Excel vba and programming in general, and so I don't know how to modify this code in order to paste two selections of cells rather than just one. The format I would like for the email is:
Good morning,

Text 1

Range 1

Text 2

Range 2

Thanks.

Can any of you please help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.HTMLBody = "Good morning,"
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "Text 1"
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & RangetoHTML(range1)
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "Text 2"
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & RangetoHTML(range2)
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "Thanks."
```

Comment: Look at DodoEgg's question above. There he reference an article about this. Follow that link and see part
Mailing a Range or Selection in the Body of an E-Mail Message